# VBA code conflict with excel 2010 and excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

When i open my excel spreadsheet with vba code in excel 2010 I get no errors, however, when i open my spreadsheet in excel 2013 i get an error saying run time error 53, 'file not found'.

I am not sure which part of my code is giving me an error as when the message pops up in excel 2013 the option to debug is greyed out.

Does anyone know why this is?

Can I use a cross excel supported code to open files?

Thanks

Comment: One reason the debug is greyed out is that the vba is password protected.  IF this is the case remove the password protection and reopen the file.